# Beginner: Python can't find 'pyodbc' package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am very new to the Python language and have a small program.  It had been working but something change and now I can't get it to run.  It's having a problem with finding 'pyodbc'.  I installed the 'pyodbc' package so I don't understand why there error.  I am using Python 3.7.6.  Thank you for your help!

**pip install pyodbc**

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in c:\users\c113850\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (4.0.28)
```

**Code:**

```
import requests
import pyodbc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import pytz 
import time
import azure.functions

page = requests.get("https://samplepage.html")

if page.status_code == 200:
    print(page.status_code)
    #print(page.content)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.title)
    rows = soup.find_all('tr')
    # for row in rows:          # Print all occurrences
    #    print(row.get_text())
    print(rows[0])
    print(rows[7])
    pjmtime = rows[0].td.get_text()
    print("PJM = ",pjmtime)

    #dt_string = "Tue Jan 21 18:00:00 EST 2020"
    dt_object = datetime.strptime(pjmtime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y")
    print("Timestamp =", dt_object)

    eastern=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    date_eastern=eastern.localize(dt_object,is_dst=None)
    date_utc=date_eastern.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    print("UTC =", date_utc)

    row = soup.find(text='PRICE').parent.parent
    name = row.select('td')[0].get_text()
    typed = row.select('td')[1].get_text()
    weighted = row.select('td')[2].get_text()
    hourly = row.select('td')[3].get_text()

    server = 'db.database.windows.net'
    database = '...'
    username = '...'
    password = '...'
    driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    print("insert into [PJMLocationalMarginalPrice] ([Name],[Type],[WeightedAverage],[HourlyIntegrated],[TimeStamp]) values(?,?,?,?,?)",
               (name,typed,weighted,hourly,date_utc))
    cursor.execute("insert into [PJMLocationalMarginalPrice] ([Name],[Type],[WeightedAverage],[HourlyIntegrated],[TimeStamp]) values (?,?,?,?,?)",
               (name,typed,weighted,hourly,date_utc))
    cnxn.commit()
else:
    print("Error: page not open")
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/C113850/PycharmProjects/Scraping101/Scraping.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Update:
I was looking at the folders under site-packages and noticed that 'pyodbc' folder is not there but 'pyodbc-4.0.28.dist-info' folder is there.
[image]

Comment: Could be an issue with [MVC++](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/663). Could you try to check what MVC++ you have installed on your end?

Comment: I am not sure what MVC++ is.

Comment: Sorry, I was just caught into the thread I was linking too. `MVC++` == `Microsoft Visual C++ Redist package`

Answer (score 0):

The module was not properly installed.

Try reinstalling it:

```
pip uninstall pyodbc
pip install pyodbc
```

If that doesn't work, try using pip3:

```
pip uninstall pyodbc
pip3 install pyodbc
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an active Python Environment when you installed 'pyodbc'. If so, you will want to activate the environment prior to running your script as you wont have access to the package outside that environment.

If not, you may just need to uninstall and re-install.

```
pip uninstall pyodbc
pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: I tried un-installing / re-installing and got the same error.  Not sure the purpose of 'active' environment.  However, I went back to the instructions I was following on the internet and activated the venu and uninstalled/reinstall all my packages and now I get the error on 'requests'.  What I did notice though was some package where installed under my user account 'c:\users\c113850\appdata\roaming\python...' and others under 'c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\...'

Answer (score 0):

I found something on Github that there is a bug in pyodbc version 4.0.28 so I downgraded to 4.0.27 and that resolved my issue.  For more info, [click here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/663).